# DocuSign JWT grant authentication - which one is responsible for the JWT token initiation?

Tags: docusignapi

Im working on integration with DocuSign eSignature API and for the authentication I chose to use JWT grant since it seems suitable to my needs.

When I use this kind of authentication grant Im not sure who is the one which responsible for the creation of the JWT token.
Is it me, a developer who works on the integration or is it my end-user which owns the DocuSign account?

I looked at DocuSign docs and didnt find answers.

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/

Answer (score 0):

Your application would be responsible to generate the JWT and the access token whenever it needs to make an API call (if it doesn't have a valid token currently).

Answer (score 0):

I’ve actually found the answer in DocuSign docs which says that the owner of the account should pass the private key to the 3rd party software in order to use JWT grant authentication -

> When creating a JSON web token (JWT) the assertion is signed by the private key. That means that in order for a third party to use JWT to impersonate your user, you would need to share your private key.

https://support.docusign.com/s/articles/DocuSign-Developer-FAQs-General-Administration-and-Authentication?language=en_US